# Addition a plone archetype after "Cancel"

Tags: plone, title, archetypes

I am developing аrchetype for plone 3.1.
My problem - if I press the button ' Cancel ' instead of ' Ok ' after addition of my type (empty or with filling of some fields), however my type is added in a portal. But I would like, that my action was canceled. (So usually occurs if to add in a portal the default plone types like Page, Image..and then "Cancel" the action). 
I am using BaseSchema for my archetype.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your type with the factory tool? Add a `factorytool.xml` file to your GenericSetup profile with the following contents to make sure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_factory" meta_type="Plone Factory Tool">
 <factorytypes>
  <type portal_type="YourPortalType"/>
 </factorytypes>
</object>
```

Otherwise, what happens is that an empty copy is created with a generated id, and you edit that in place. The factory tool creates this type within it's managed boundaries and will only move it into place when you save the first time, thus ensuring no copy is already there when you hit `Cancel`.